# How to store a base 2 number in a register?

Tags: assembly, binary, ascii, mips, mars-simulator

but my instructor is not responding. I have an extra credit question for a MIPS program as follows:

```
Extra credit covers binary to ASCII data type conversion. It is useful 
to convert the 2’s complement integer into an ASCII string so that it
can be displayed on the monitor. Derive a binary-to-ASCII conversion
routine, BinarytoASCII, for converting a 2’s complement integer stored 
in a0 register into an ASCII string stored in v0 register. The value 
initially in a0 is restricted to be within the range -999 to +999. After   
the algorithm completes execution, v0 contains the sign of the value 
initially stored in a0. The following three bytes contain the three 
ASCII codes corresponding to the three decimal digits representing its
magnitude. This algorithm always produces a string of four characters 
independent of the sign and magnitude of the integer being converted.
```

Maybe I am not reading this problem correctly, but is it not impossible to store a binary value directly into a register in MIPS? It seems as though this is asking for a decimal to ASCII conversion. If I am wrong can you show how to place a base-2 number into register in MIPS? thank you

Comment: You are overthinking it -- what do you think gets stored in a register to begin with `:)` (all a computer knows is `0` or `1`) So the prof basically wants you to take the content of the register and convert it to a series of ASCII `'0'` and `'1'` (e.g. `and` and `shift` and add, e,g, `or` with `'0'`...), then reverse the string to recover the original order)

Comment: Have a look at [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/). `0x30` is `'0'` and `0x31` is `'1'`.

Comment: @David, he wants it converted to decimal, not binary. (But it doesn’t mention decimal until the next to last sentence.)

Comment: Ah, good catch, so add the manual base2 to base10 conversion instead of just `shift and add`.

Comment: Values in registers are already encoded in bits (MIPS register is physically 32 bits (0 or 1) and **nothing** else). When the debugger shows you the `a0` contains `1234`, it takes original 32 bit pattern, and interprets it as integer (i.e. it does the conversion to string), and displays that on screen, but the register is still just bit pattern... (i.e. if that `1234` was hexadecimal, then the register contains 16 zero bits in top and then `0001_0010_0011_0100` ... if decimal, I'm too lazy to convert base10 1234 to base2 ... whatever, you hopefully get the idea now).

Comment: I.e. you can start by `li $a0,999` (that's loading base 2 encoded value `999` into `a0`, the conversion from decimal 999 into base 2 bit pattern is done by assembler during assembly process), then your magic, then `v0` at end should contain value `0x20393939` (i.e. four char string `" 999"` (0x20 is space in ASCII)) (if I understand the task definition correctly, it's sort of "not precise" enough by my standards, so I'm partly guessing what exactly is expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Numbers in registers are in binary**.  This is why a 32-bit register can store signed values from `-2^31 .. 2^31-1`, using 2's complement encoding.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

If the native storage format in a register was decimal, bit-shifts left and right would multiply/divide by powers of 10, not powers of 2.

---

Encoding is separate from value.  Given a bit-pattern of `0b11111111111111111111110000011001` in a 32-bit register, you can describe / represent the encoded value as

- `-999` decimal, interpreting it as signed 2's complement
- `0xfffffc19` unsigned hex
- `037777776031` octal
- `0b11111111111111111111110000011001` binary

These are all the same number, just different ways of expressing either the mathematical value (as a negative decimal number), or the 2's complement bit-pattern (hex, octal and binary).

Usually hex is only used to describe the bit-pattern, so you wouldn't usually see a negative hex number like `-0x3e7`.

---

It's a common misunderstanding that numbers in registers or memory are "in hex".  Hex is a serialization format for binary numbers, allowing them to be stored as text in a human-readable format.  A number is only in hex if it's stored as a sequence of ASCII characters.

An ASCII string of decimal digits is another way to serialize numbers, and that's what you're being asked to do here.

Hex and decimal are commonly used in asm source code, but the assembler will assemble your numbers into 32-bit binary words.  (Or 16-bit immediates as part of the instruction stream, for something like `addiu $t0, $t1, 0x1234`)

You can talk about a binary number's value using hex, but it's actually stored as base 2 bits.