# What changed when the octal was substituted by the hexadecimal?

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, byte, octal

I've been reading somethings about binary and bits, and i found something saying that sometime ago octal was used to ''simplify'' binary, but then it was substituted by heaxdecimal.
I didn't quite understand it though, did it just change how you read the byte, did it make files smaller?
Could anyone give me an explanation on this? Wikipedia and other ''tech sites'' don't seem to give much information on this topic. Feel free to recommend a book on this matter if you know one, i'd like to learn coding and computer science by books rather than only youtube lectures.

Comment: Hex and octal are text serialization formats for binary (or numbers in general).  Computers have always been binary, and still are; nothing changed about how they work, just how humans like to write representations of the data in a register or a byte in memory, or the bytes of a file.  See [How to store a base 2 number in a register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53894593) for example.  You can still use either hex or octal to dump or write numbers.

Comment: Modern machines use 8 bits (a byte) as a basic unit. 8 bits are 2 hexadecimal digits exactly. On a 9-bit machine, octal would be preferable because 9 bits = 3 octal digits.

Comment: The retrocomputing stackexchange is a pretty good resource for this type of question. See for example here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12101/what-is-the-hex-versus-octal-timeline